# Binary Search C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl

I have a vector of unordered_map which is sorted based on the comparer function I defined. I would like to use binary search to look for one of the value using the comparer function as well. However, binary search only return bool and I need the index / iterator of the result. What could I do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

//!!!!!   a must be sorted using cmp. Question indicates that it is.        
it = lower_bound(a.begin, a.end(), value, cmp);

//Check that we have actually found the value. 
//If the requested value is missing
//then we will have the value before where the requested value 
//would be inserted.
if(it == a.end() || !cmp(*it, value))
{
   //element not found
} 
else
{
   //element found
}
```

Comment: lower_bound seems to be much slower than simple "any matching value". Assume { 1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7 }.
The middle is 5 - a sought for value. But lower_bound will go left. It is inoptimal. I can suppose O(Log(N)) solution of finding left boundary. But it is excess. I'm very upset of this. However there is a C function ::bsearch.

Comment: `!cmp(*it, value)` is always true if `it!=a.end()`. You should reverse the arguments.

Answer (score 15):

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

it = lower_bound(a.begin, a.end(), value, cmp);
```

Comment: -1 lower_bound will not necessarily return the element. If the element is missing it will return the element before it would be if it were in the vector.

Comment: it's still wise to use lower_bound. Take the iterator, check if it's dereferenceable. If it is, dereference it and check with the searched element. If it is the element, you have it, else it's not in there.