# How should i go about a binary search algorithm

Tags: c#

For an acedemic exercise with our class, we need to make a program that can perform a binary search, and then display the index of the target. Here is my code right now:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Binarysearch
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var target = 10; //Defines what the program will be searching for
            int[] array = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 17, 19, 21, 99999 };
            var last = array.Last();
            var first = array.First();
            var mid = array[array.Length / 2];
            bool found = false;

            while (first <= last && found == false)
            {
                if (mid > target)
                {

                }
                if (mid == target)
                {
                    bool found = true;
                }
                if (mid < target)
                {

                }
            }
            if (first > last){ //If the target was not found
                Console.WriteLine("The target " + target + "was not located.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (found == true) //If the target was found
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The target " + target + " was located at index " + mid); // Prints the final outcome.
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem i am running into:
Should i do this by deleting the upper / lower half of the array, finding the middle and repeating? if i do this, it will eventually find the target, but i dont think it will be able to find the index as the rest of the array would be ruined.

How should i go about this?

Thanks :p

Comment: A search never deletes anything. It's a **search**, not a **seek or destroy** operation.

Comment: There is no shortage of examples of binary search algorithms on the web, and even on Stack Overflow. If you are looking for advice as to how it should be done, or is commonly done, that would be the first place to start. I certainly do agree with the previous comment though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary Search C++ STL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284049/binary-search-c-stl)

Answer (score 0):

A Binary Search is in charge of finding the index of your target within a sorted array. It is not supposed to alter the original array in any sort of way.

Here's an examply of a Binary Search written in C#:

```
public static int BinarySearch(int[] intArr, int target)
{
    int min = 1, max = intArr.Length;
    int mid;

    while (min <= max)
    {
        mid = min + (max - min) / 2;
        if (intArr[mid] == target)
            return mid;

        else if (intArr[mid] < target)
            min = mid + 1;
        else
            max = mid - 1          
    }
    return -1; // Target was not found within the array.
}
```

Usage:

```
int[] intArr = new int[] { 1, 5, 7, 9, 12, 15, 16, 17, 27, 28, 222, 235, 567, 578, 890 };
MessageBox.Show(BinarySearch(intArr, 99).ToString());
```

Comment: what does the line public static int BinarySearch(int[] intArr, int target) mean?

Comment: It's the deceleration of the method.